# How to solve the conflict "Type exists in both..."?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a lot errors like this in downloaded WP8 app.

> The type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector' exists in both
>   'c:\Program Files (x86)\Syncfusion\Essential
>   Studio\11.1.0.21\Assemblies\4.0\Windows
>   Phone8\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll' and 'c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.Phone.dll'.

It happens in  Name.g.cs files. I don't need to use Syncfusion. How to tell app not to use it?

**Edit:**

packages.config content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Rx-Core" version="2.0.20823" targetFramework="wp80" />
  <package id="Rx-Interfaces" version="2.0.20823" targetFramework="wp80" />
  <package id="Rx-Linq" version="2.0.20823" targetFramework="wp80" />
  <package id="Rx-Main" version="2.0.20823" targetFramework="wp80" />
  <package id="Rx-PlatformServices" version="2.0.20823" targetFramework="wp80" />
  <package id="Rx-Silverlight" version="2.0.20823" targetFramework="wp80" />
  <package id="sqlite-net" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="wp80" />
  <package id="sqlite-net-wp8" version="3.8.5" targetFramework="wp80" />
  <package id="WPtoolkit" version="4.2013.08.16" targetFramework="wp80" />
  <package id="Yandex.Maps" version="1.02.4721.1342" targetFramework="wp80" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Did you try removing the reference to the library, or do you use it elsewhere in the app?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw, there is no references. I also tried file search in project folder. It found "syncfusion" only in two .cache files in obj/x86/Debug. Deleting this files gives nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your Project -> Right click -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Extensions -> uncheck syncfusion.

Comment: There is no Syncfusion references checked. That's why I can't solve it easy.

Comment: Try to paste content of your _packages.config_ file

Comment: added details to my question.